# Why does this solution to 5-3 work? Didn't the Prince get eaten?

Tags: storyteller

In Storyteller, a puzzle game about telling stories that fit a title, I accidentally solved Chapter 5.3 - *Duplicity: A Kiss and a Curse* without understanding why my solution worked.

- Kiss, Witch, Prince: Prince refuses to kiss the Witch.
- Forest, Witch, Prince: Witch turns Prince into a frog.
- Cauldron, Witch: Witch eats from cauldron, presumably eating the frog.
- Kiss, Witch, Prince: Prince and the Witch kiss.

[image: Kiss and a Curse solved]

When I look at these events, it looks like the Witch turned the Prince into a frog, the Witch ate frog stu, then kissed the Prince who she just turned into stu.

Why does this puzzle solution work? How does the Prince come back to life after being eaten? Am I misinterpreting something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Witch isn't eating the Frog Prince. The cauldron transforms the Witch between her pretty and ugly forms. The Prince will deny a kiss from the Ugly Witch but always accept a kiss from the Pretty Witch, even if she transformed him into a frog earlier. (Presumably, the prince doesn't recognize her post-transformation). The Ugly Witch will turn the Prince into a frog in the Forest if the Prince refused to kiss her earlier.

The puzzle is solved if the Witch to turns the prince into a frog and the prince kisses the Witch, but it can be done in either order. This can be seen with an alternative solution where the Witch kisses the Prince *before* turning him into a frog.

[image]